# Programmatically add tags to scenario in cucumber?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, cucumber, capybara

I am trying to create an alias that would run cucumber scenarios in browser so I can watch them run if they're failing.  I have tried setting an environment variable, and then doing something like

```
if ENV['CUCUMBER_INTERACTIVE']
  Capybara.current_driver = :selenium
end
```

However, it seems that the @javascript does more than just specify the driver.  All my tests fail when I change the driver like this, unless I manually add the @javascript tag.

Is there anyway I can create something like the following?

```
if ENV['CUCUMBER_INTERACTIVE']
  Before do |scenario|
    scenario.add_tag('@javascript')
  end
end
```

Comment: Your idea should work, can you tell us how the tests are failing?  Is there a consistent error coming up?

Comment: It seems that when I change the driver, there's no awareness of the new context.  In particular, I have a step that creates a user and then logs in.  When I run the test with the CUCUMBER_INTERACTIVE flag, then the user can't be found.  The scenario runs, however, if I just add the '@javascript' tag.

Comment: Could you try setting the `current_driver` to `:javascript` instead of `:selenium`?  See if that makes a difference?

Comment: User not found is due to using out-of-process browser instead of rack_test. Use shared db connection by monkeypatching ActiveRecord::Base.connection to fix.